# How to keep the connection alive in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have set the max value of keep-alive interval but still it is expire with in 5 minute..

[image]

Comment: What version of WB is that? If the timeout has no effect then it might be a bug. What does the log say (Help -> Show log)?

Comment: its 6.3 version...